# How to show two map with one script?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I found a problem about the show two maps using two ids; map and map1.Firstly, I used document.getElementByID('map') which is working. But I wanna call two ids,  map & map1 below the code which doesn't work.

Thanks.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Your Website</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      // Load google map
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelectorAll("#gmap","#gmap1"),  {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
        zoom: 3,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        panControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false
      });




    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="padding-bottom:10px;"><input type="text" name="address" value="O. J. Brochs g 16a, Bergen" style="width:400px;border:1px solid black"><input type="button" name="search" value="Geocode"></div>
    <div id="coords"></div>
    <div id="gmap" style="width:370px; height:300px;"></div>

    <div style="padding-bottom:10px;"><input type="text" name="address" value="O. J. Brochs g 16a, Bergen" style="width:400px;border:1px solid black"><input type="button" name="search" value="Geocode"></div>
    <div id="coords"></div>
    <div id="gmap1" style="width:370px; height:300px;"></div>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with your call to [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll), if you want to use multiple selectors you must use a single string separating the selectors with commas:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#gmap,#gmap1")
```

Comment: can you show example about the single string separtiong the selectors with commas ? Thanks bro.

Comment: there is an example in my answer - see the code above

Comment: The API for maps doesnt say that its possible to initialise 2 maps with a single call (see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map), looks like you have to make 2 separate calls

Comment: I just want one Object brother.

Answer (score 1):

Although multiple map initialization is possible, you can't do it with one object. Creating variable `map` holds lots of attributes including its position in page and therefore it must belong to **only one** map. You can reference `map` to another variable, but you cannot hold two maps information in one `google.maps.Map()` object.

Think that if it was allowed. Centers, markers, etc. everything is as same in two maps. However, they are two different maps and their ids are different(object ids).

Suppose you changed the center of the first map. If you call `map.getCenter();` whose maps' center will be retrieved?

In order to avoid confliction, it is not allowed to pass multiple selection to one `google.maps.Map()` object constructor.

In short, you need to create your maps with different variables.